# how to read large excel file in java without increasing VM

Tags: java, apache-poi

How to read large(95+MB) excel workbook with more then 10 sheets in java using POI library without increasing JVM(like -Xmx1G). If we run jar file without increasing VM got OutOfMemory error. How can I optimize this issue in coding itself instead of increasing VM?

Comment: What is it you need to do with the sheet? Do you need it in memory all at once, please be more specific.

Comment: i have a excel workbook (95mb) it has 15 sheets, each sheet has different fields. i have to read and store the data's to the corresponding fields in the SQL database.

Comment: Apache POI has a streaming/event model for reading excel files, which is quite efficient (memory wise) and which doesn't load the whole sheet into memory. I suggest you take a look at that. See http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/

Comment: thanks sir, i used HSSF of POI to read , and while running jar file i manually increasing VM to -Xmx1G. if i run jar file normally without increasing VM means i get OutOfMemory error.

Comment: As stated use the event model not the dom model (the last one reads everything in memory, the other one uses streaming). So basically change the way you read files.

Answer (score 5):

There are no clever "optimizations" that will allow you to continue with your current approach and run using less memory.

You are going to need to change your program so that it does not load the entire workbook into memory.

As @M.Deinum points out, Apache POI provides an alternative way to process Excel files where you get a sequence of parser events rather than an in-memory representation of each entire spreadsheet.  Switching from the in-memory model to the event-based model will entail a significant amount of recoding of your application.  But if you cannot afford the memory you have *no other practical alternatives*.